# Wordpress form that creates a page

Tags: wordpress

Basically I am looking for a way for my site administrator to have a form where they can enter data about a person. For example, enter images, video and statistics on an athlete. This form would have name, physical characteristics, player stats for different sports, etc.

I would like to take this information and have it go into a pre-formatted page or post in WordPress.

This would totally remove the need for the user to know HTML and allow me to be creative with CSS. Does anyone know of a plugin or any such thing that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using one of the following two plugins: [Pods](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pods/) or [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

Comment: Pods 2.0 is pretty powerful, we're here to help if you need it too.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I really like the layout of the [Types Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/)

What I would do is set up a Custom Post Type and name it something like "Special Page". From there, you can ensure the layout of the page will be determined primarily by Custom Fields. If you don't even want to grant the author the ability to write any actual content, I'm fairly certain you can disable the Content Editor when you create the Custom Post Type.